# C# local database update error

Tags: c#, database, runtime-error, sql-server-ce

The issue is that I'm trying to write into a table called `Login`. It has a few columns, there's a column with no data in (null) that I'm trying to insert / update the column is `SuperSecretKey - nvarchar(100)`.

Heres the code:

```html
public void InsertSecretKey(String SuperKey, int IDKey)
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Login SET SuperSecretKey = @SuperKey WHERE Key=@IDKEY;";
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuperKey", SuperKey);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDKey", IDKey);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Here's the error:

> There was an error parsing the query.
>   [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 51,Token in error = Key ]

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You are using Sql Server Compact then do not tag this question with MySql

Answer (score 5):

Key is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). The error is pretty specific: `offset = 51` => at position 51 there's the word `key`. It actually tells you: `Token in error = Key`.

You need to escape it, e.g. `[key]`. It is a good practice to escape *all* your fieldnames, tables etc.:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Login] SET [SuperSecretKey] = @SuperKey WHERE [Key]=@IDKEY;";
```

What isn't a reserved keyword in the current version of SQL Server may be in a [new/future release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx#sectionToggle1)<sup>1</sup>. Most ORM's etc. that generate ("dynamic") queries escape these values by default, just to be "on the safe side".

<sup>1</sup> Even if a keyword isn't on that list *currently*, it may be added in a future-future release. You'll probably be safe with names like `CustomerId` and `MyVerySpecificName` but generic words like `Key` <sub>(you just found that out)</sub>, `GUID`, `Version` or `Descending`, though currently not reserved, are just not (future-)safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

Key is a reserverd keyword

use brackets to escape it `[key]`

For the full list check [`Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)